# How to tell if a given year and month is in the future in Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

In Classic ASP, how can I get a true or false value indicating that a given year and month is in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this, assuming you don't know the day of month.

```
dateToTest = CDate(givenYear & "-" & givenMonth & "-" & "01")

inthefuture = dateToTest > now()
```